# Unable to locate element when browser in background using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to automate this program to be handled in background while I can do my work, but I found out it gives "Unable to locate element" error when I don't have the browser active in front of other processes (like watching it). It follows people on Twitter, but like I want the program do its work. Everything is smooth when the browser is active, but as I switch to other works on my laptop, it doesn't locate the element even though it's visible.

I'm new and still learning, so I don't know if there are limitations to Selenium.

```
def to_follow_delay():
    def to_follow_delay_2():
        try:
            driver.get(next(urls))
            def follow_user():
                sleep(5)
                followuser = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div')
                sleep(5)
                followuser.click()
                #followuser = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div')))
                print("Follow successful")
                print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - starting4))

                followedper_runcounter.set(followedper_runcounter.get() + 1)
                followedcounter.set(followedcounter.get() + 1)
                return operation_follow()

            timer4 = threading.Timer(tofollowdelayvalue_txt.get(), follow_user)
            timer4.start()
            starting4 = time.time()
        except StopIteration:
            print('No more urls.')
            return

       
    timer5 = threading.Timer(5, to_follow_delay_2)
    timer5.start()
```

Comment: 1. you could launch the chrome in headless mode and you wont interact with the page
2. (Not sure that it works, but you can try) is to move to the element, so that the focus switches back to the chrome "action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(element).click().perform()

Comment: @Cassano it sound like you are using a Mac. Is that correct?

Comment: No, I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried using Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue usually gets resolved when you use headless mode.
For Firefox the settings that you would have to include would be

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('-headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile, executable_path = 'C:\\some path\\geckodriver.exe', options=options)
```